# Mongoose using dynamic maps vs using nested documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am building this model schema in mongoose where companies have a field called 'address'.

I could handle this field like this:

```
address: {
  type: Map,
},
field2: Number,
```

But I want to validate this map, so I created a validator prop:

```
address: {
  type: Map,
  validate: {
    validator: (map) => {
      const title = map.get('city');
      const content = map.get('street');
      const likes = map.get('number');
      if (
        title && typeof city === 'string' &&
        content && typeof street === 'string' &&
        likes && typeof number === 'number'
      ) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    },
    message: 'Address map does not contain necessary fields',
  },
},
```

Is this the best way of handling an object like this inside a collection document? Or should I use another Schema (which would eventually lead to each adderss becoming a sub document with their own ids and such) to model the address object? Which one is better performance wise? Which one is better query-wise?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Embedding the address inside company is good, this way you can read the company and its addresses faster. There is no need to create separate collection for address, it will be a bit slower because of joining, and querying addresses  independently doesn't make much sense.

Comment: It depends on your domain/use-cases. Since it seems you want it as a sub-document, I would suggest using a separate schema for the address, but use the address schema as the type in the company schema. That way you can separate your concerns of validating an address, from the rest of the company validation. I am not familiar with any performance concerns of using sub-documents either way. Splitting of the address into its own collection (registering the address schema), might be a solution too, but again, it depends on the use-cases you have.

Comment: Hey folks! Thanks for the answer. I do think there is a difference between sub-document and a map inside a document. Sub-documents are packed with an ID, timestamps and such. I do not want that, I'd prefer having a Map that maps the address of a company, but I do need to require all the fields, and since I'm using the Map type, I can require a map called address through mongoose, but I can't validate the fields of a map through the required method in mongoose, and that's why I created the validator function there haha. Is there any problem in structuring things this way?